# How can I connect to WebSocket server in swift?

Tags: swift, websocket

I heard Apple recently added web sockets which allows a server to push data but i did't get any single example or any documentation.

I want to make a app where i can have the data from a websocket server can anyone help me how can i do that.
May i have to download a third party library?

Comment: Use the official `URLSessionWebSocketTask` class for WebSocket communication. The best documentation is an official one - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionwebsockettask But be aware, that it requires iOS 13 and later. If you need to support previous versions of iOS, try websocket library StarScream. It can be found at GitHub.

Comment: shall i prefer swift library over any third party library? actually some people say there might be some security issues on third party library.